# RPATH in .pro-file not working

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qmake, rpath

I'm trying to add `$ORIGIN` to the rpath variable of my program.

I added the following line to my .pro-file:

```
unix: QMAKE_RPATHDIR += \$$ORIGIN
```

And verified that the command is really added by checking the compilation output. The call to g++ that qmake generates looks this:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/sky/Qt/5.5/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN -Wl...
```

As you can see, origin is added (together with some other values). However, if I check the value of rpath using `readelf`, originis not listed. Instead it show an "empty" entry (just two colons) besides the entrys added by qmake:

```
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Bibliothek rpath: [/home/sky/Qt/5.5/gcc_64::/home/sky/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib]
```

What am I missing here? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is here ["qmake and rpath"](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.user/6883):

> You have to use the $ORIGIN feature of the runtime linker. 
>   Unfortunately, due to some brilliant foresight of the loader devs,
>   they  used '$' as prefix, which makes it a royal pain in the ass to
>   pass  around.  It's impossible to use it in QMAKE_RPATHDIR.  You must
>   instead use:
>
> ```
> QMAKE_LFLAGS += '-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN\''
> ```
>
> so that it survives both the project file as well as the Makefile.

---

In your command line it goes to shell as `-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN` and `$ORIGIN` is expanded, since the $ dollar sign is interpreted by the shell. It should be quoted. Example of such quotation is also provided in [LD.SO(8) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html): `gcc -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib'`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!